# Deploy Sanic server next to Nginx

Tags: nginx, deployment, sanic

I'm trying to deploy a Sanic app next to Nginx. I want Nginx to handle:

1. File serving (my SPA and other assets)
2. Certbot/letsencrypt ssl (can do without)

And I want Sanic to handle my API endpoints.

I know how to handle each separately. However, I don't know how to make them run next to each other. As far as I know, you can't have two services listening on the same TCP port. If that's the case, should I just make Nginx act as a reverse proxy to Sanic? If so, how would you go about it?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Even it's inside docker, this example shows overall principles of how to setup sanic behind nginx https://github.com/itielshwartz/sanic-nginx-docker-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my preferred way to run Sanic, behind nginx as you described. Then just proxy to Sanic which is listening on some other port.

```
server {
   ...
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://sanic-app:1234/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I went for